# How to change the call location identifier language?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, languages

I have changed everything in my rooted HTC One SU (t528w) mobile to remove chinese characters. There is no chinese display in my mobile except one thing. When I call to anyone or gets call it shows the number location identification in Chinese.

I asked my Chinese friend to tell me what is it. He says its caller location display like India, Shanghai

How can I change this chinese in English? I am on Android 4.1.1

Thanks

Comment: Are you in China? This information might be provided by the network operator over the network, in which case it would always be Chinese.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes I am in China. Oh that means if I come back to India. I will get that information in english ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I checked with the Android phone bought from India. when someone calls on that its shows location in English but in my cell its shows in Chinese. So this proves that network provider is not providing the loction. Please help me to fix this. Anyother way to fix this

Comment: It's very likely some pre-installed app. I've never seen this extended CallerID stuff on any Android device by default (it usually shows either the number, or the name if found in your contacts). Check your *Settings->Apps* to see if there's some Chinese CallerID app, freeze (disable) it. If you want that feature badly, just pick one of the many alternatives available on Google Play.

Comment: @Izzy This the only thing left to get change to English from my Handset. This feature is with everyhandset now. All my friends has this feature . Whenever I call them they get my call location . This was not in Android version lower than 4 I think.

Comment: @Izzy I can see one serice running in app "CallLocationProvider" This can be the service which shows up the location .Does you have the same?

Comment: @Izzy when I checked the system/app folder I see callerLocation.apk and CallerLocation.odex
How can I repleace them with engllish . Do you have the english version of this

Comment: @Izzy my Galaxy Nexus & Nexus 4 (both stock) display the origin of the caller's number whenever they aren't already in my Contacts.

Comment: @AndrewLott Do you have callerLocation.apk in system/app

Comment: You could try to disable this app (if it turns up in *Settings->Apps* and you can disable it there) or, if rooted, just freeze it with e.g. TitaniumBackup or some other bloatware-remover. Then simply use any CallerID app from playstore if you want that feature back. And no, I have this on none of my phones (at least I didn't notice); maybe that was added with JellyBean?